# How to call TVF that returns multiple rowsets in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

U-SQL TVF can also return multiple rowsets, I can create such function successfully but unable to call such function with error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       E_CSC_USER_MULTIPLERESULTFUNCTIONNOTALLOWED: Multiple-result function call is not allowed in this context.
Description:
Multiple-result return values must be assigned to a list of rowset variables.
Resolution:
Add a separate statement that calls the multiple-result function and assigns the results to a list of rowset variables.

Thanks,
Nasir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(@r1, @r2) = TVFreturning2rowsets();
```

Then you can select from them individually:

```
@x = SELECT * FROM @r1 ...;
@y = SELECT * FROM @r2 ...;
```